# How to make a fade in effect slider javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, slider

Hi I need to create a fade-out / fade-in animation when i click on those arrow switcher instead of slidding pictures and description card to left/right

my javascript is doing a simple slide i need to change that

searched a lot, i have no idea how to do it please

(Hi here is all my code, my javascript is doing a simple slide i need to change that

I need to create a fade-out / fade-in animation when i click on those arrow switcher instead of slidding it to left or right

searched a lot, i have no idea how to do it please)

```js
var options = {
  accessibility: true,
  prevNextButtons: true,
  pageDots: true,
  setGallerySize: false,
  arrowShape: {
    x0: 10,
    x1: 60,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 60,
    y2: 45,
    x3: 15
  }
};

var carousel = document.querySelector('[data-carousel]');
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-cell');
var flkty = new Flickity(carousel, options);

flkty.on('scroll', function () {
  flkty.slides.forEach(function (slide, i) {
    var image = slides[i];
    var x = (slide.target + flkty.x) * -1/3;
    image.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
body {
     background-color: #000;
     margin: 0;
}

 .overlay {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(14, 29, 51, 0.8), rgba(14, 29, 51, 0.2));
}

 .hero-slider {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
     overflow: hidden;
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell .inner {
     position: relative;
     top:71.2%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell .inner .subtitle {
     font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
     font-size: 2.2rem;
     line-height: 1.2em;
     font-weight: 200;
     font-style: italic;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     margin-bottom: 5px;
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell .inner .title {
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 3rem;
     line-height: 1.2em;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     margin-bottom: 400px;
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell .inner .btn {
     position: absolute;
     top: 10%;
     left: 65%;
     right: 4%;
     border: 1px solid rgb(243, 138, 138);
     padding: 24px 28px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1rem;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     text-decoration: none;
         
}

 .hero-slider .carousel-cell .inner .btn:hover {
     background: #fff;
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-prev-next-button {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     background: transparent;
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
     background: transparent;
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
     fill: white;
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-page-dots {
     bottom: 30px;
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot {
     width: 30px;
     height: 4px;
     opacity: 1;
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     border: 0 solid white;
     border-radius: 0;
}

 .hero-slider .flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
     background: #f00;
     border: 0 solid #f00;
}

.NFT {

    width: 50%;
}

.carac {
    margin-top: 5%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.branche {

    font-weight: bold;
    
    
}

.trait1 {
margin-top: -1%;
margin-right: 60px;
margin-left: 60px;
color: rgb(46, 74, 231);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 3px rgb(46, 74, 231);;
    
      
}

.ligne4 {
    margin-top: 10%;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.vote {

    display: flex;

}

.carac2 {

    margin-top: 5%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}

.branche2 {

    font-weight: bold;
    
}

.branche3 {

    justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responive Carousel Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="hero-slider" data-carousel>
    <div class="carousel-cell" style="background-image: url(img/vaporwave.jpg);">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="subtitle">Nom du NFT</h3>
            <img class="title" src="img/NFT1.png" width="500px">
            <div class="btn">Elon#21

                <div class="carac">
                    <p class="branche">Branche <p>
                    <p>Société </p>
            
                </div>
                <div class="trait1"><hr></div>
                    
    
                    <div class="carac">
                        <p class="branche">Cibles <p>
                        <p>Startup, TPE, PME </p>
                
                    </div>
                        <hr class="trait1">
    
                        <div class="carac">
                            <p class="branche">Spécialité <p>
                            <p>Réseaux sociaux & QVT </p>
                    
                        </div>
                        
                            <hr class="trait1">
    
                            <div class="ligne4">
    
                                <p>Caracteristique <p>
                                
                            </div>
    
                                <hr class="trait1">
    
                                <div class="carac2">
                                    <p class="branche2">Community Managment <p>
                                        <p class="branche3"> Photographie <p>
    
                                </div>
    
                                    <br>
                                        
                                    <div class="carac2">
                                        <p class="branche2">Identité visuelle <p>
                                            <p class="branche3">Vidéo <p>
        
                                    </div>
    
                                            <div class="carac2">
                                                <p class="branche2">Site Web <p>
                                                <p class="branche3">Média <p>
                
                                            </div>
    
            
        </div>
    
            </div>
            

        
    </div>

    
    <div class="carousel-cell" style="background-image: url(img/vaporwave.jpg);">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="inner">
            <h3 class="subtitle">Nom du NFT</h3>
            <img class="title" src="img/NFT2.png" width="600px">
            <div class="btn">Elon#21

                <div class="carac">
                    <p class="branche">Branche <p>
                    <p>Société </p>
            
                </div>
                <div class="trait1"><hr></div>
                    
    
                    <div class="carac">
                        <p class="branche">Cibles <p>
                        <p>Startup, TPE, PME </p>
                
                    </div>
                        <hr class="trait1">
    
                        <div class="carac">
                            <p class="branche">Spécialité <p>
                            <p>Réseaux sociaux & QVT </p>
                    
                        </div>
                        
                            <hr class="trait1">
    
                            <div class="ligne4">
    
                                <p>Caracteristique <p>
                                
                            </div>
    
                                <hr class="trait1">
    
                                <div class="carac2">
                                    <p class="branche2">Community Managment <p>
                                        <p class="branche3"> Photographie <p>
    
                                </div>
    
                                    <br>
                                        
                                    <div class="carac2">
                                        <p class="branche2">Identité visuelle <p>
                                            <p class="branche3">Vidéo <p>
        
                                    </div>
    
                                            <div class="carac2">
                                                <p class="branche2">Site Web <p>
                                                <p class="branche3">Média <p>
                
                                            </div>
    
            
        </div>
        
            
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```